# Html file to Aspose slide conversion

Tags: html, css, aspose

I am converting html file to aspose slides ini c#, if i use table the table is being extracted, but along with that, thehere is duplication of data..And when i am using other tags like

the data is being extracted, ut the css stylings are not retained

Answer (score 0):

I have observed your requirements and regret to share that at present the support for importing HTML table inside Aspose.Slides for .NET is unavailable. We have already logged an issue as new feature request with ID **SLIDESNET-37059** in our issue tracking system to provide the requested support. We will share notification with you once the support will be available in API.

I am working as Support developer/ Evangelist at Aspose.

We are sorry for your inconvenience,