# Java Library to create MS Office PowerPoint presentation slides from a JSP page

Tags: jsp, apache-poi, powerpoint

How can I create ppt slides from my JSP page? I intend to create the slides from the HTML table data into the MS Office PowerPoint presentation document

I have seen Apache POI and Aspose Slides for Java but I also want to know which other options are available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend that you take a look at SlideMight, a utility for merging data with PowerPoint templates; both text and images, in slides and tables. The usage is in principle similar to mail merge, with some more advanced stuff.

Possibly a solution for you would be first write your data in a YAML, JSON or XML file; then invoke the command-line version of SlideMight.

See [www.slidemight.com](http://www.slidemight.com).

Disclaimer: I am the developer and seller of SlideMight.

Answer (score 2):

I have observed your requirements and regret to share that at present the support for importing HTML table inside Aspose.Slides for .NET/Java is unavailable. We have already logged an issue as new feature request with ID **SLIDESJAVA-36451** in our issue tracking system to provide the requested support. We will share notification with you once the support will be available in API.

Please also check this [Stackoverflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44151694/html-file-to-aspose-slide-conversion) for your kind reference.
I am working as Support developer/ Evangelist at Aspose.

We are sorry for your inconvenience,